# How to move sprites from the Top to Bottom using Cocos2d Android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-android, 2d-games

I am trying to move a sprite from the top to bottom of the screen but I do not have any success at this moment...  I've used [the following as example](http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/).

In this case, the sprites, are moving from left to right, and in my case I want to move them from top to bottom.

Can anyone give me a help on this?

How can I proceed to make this work?

Comment: You should include the relevant code in the question (not just a link)

Answer (score 0):

Use CCMoveToAction  for moving a sprite.
For the movement of sprite from top to bottom

```
    //to get total size of display
    CGSize winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().displaySize();
    CCMoveTo moveTo = CCMoveTo.action(1,
            CGPoint.ccp(width, ));
```